# How can I subset columns within mutate()?

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's imagine I have length and type (A, B,C) as variables. If I wanted to obtain a new column with length - average length I can do:

```
tibble %>%
  mutate(length - mean(length))
```

But if I want to obtain the difference between the length and the average length of all the cases of the same type I need a way to subset the second length. This won't do the trick:

```
tibble %>%
  mutate(length - mean(length[type == type])
```

Is there a way to do this type of subsetting within mutate?

Comment: `tibble %>% group_by(type) %>% mutate(length = length - mean(length)) %>% ungroup()`

Comment: Or with base R using new pipe: `df |> transform(length = length - ave(length, type, FUN=mean))`

Comment: I didn't want to solve that specific problem, it was just an example. I wanted to know how  can I subset within mutate().